# Is J-1 tax exempt even with a previous J-1 (with no income) visit to US?

Tags: usa, visa, taxes

I have a question about the tax exemption with J-1 VISA.
I'm an italian citizen doing research in the US with a J-1 VISA (research scholar) since July, 2015. I read about the tax treaty with Italy and the 2 years tax exemption. 
In late 2013 I did 3 months visiting research in another US state (J-1 VISA research scholar short term) without any income (I had personal funds).
Do those 3 months affect my possible tax exemption resulting in a resident alien status?

I really thank anyone who can help me with this issue!

Ciao

Michele

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [technical explanation](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/tax-policy/treaties/Documents/teitaly.pdf) to the [treaty](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/tax-policy/treaties/Documents/italy.pdf), we can see this (I added the **bold**):

> The exemption from tax applies for a period **not exceeding two
>   years from the date he first visits** the host State for the purpose of teaching or engaging in
>   research at the qualifying educational institution or medical facility there.

So it appears that the clock starts ticking from your first visit.

Keep in mind that this exemption is only for the income you get for the research itself, any other income you earn in the US is not exempt.

Comment: Thank you littleadv. I didn't go into the technical explanation and there was the answer. Just a technical clarification (probably a stupid one). The fact that the exemption "applies for a period not exceeding two years from the date he first visits the host State". For host State it is intended any US State? If the first visit with J-1 was in another State (like in my case) does change something? Thanks again!

Comment: @Michele no, the State refers to the United States as a whole.